# TextField Not Editable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have to attached variables to `TextField` and I want that variables will be deleted as a whole and not editable. Is it possible?

Codesandbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-material-ui-and-yup-forked-mk431?file=/src/form/Form.js)

**code**

```
  <CardContent>
    <Autocomplete
      value={values.variable}
      options={variables}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option === value}
      getOptionLabel={(data) => data}
      onChange={(e, value) => {
        setFieldValue("variable", "");
        setFieldValue("message", `${values.message} ${value}`);
      }}
      fullWidth
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          name="variable"
          size="small"
          variant="outlined"
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          helperText={touched.variable ? errors.variable : ""}
          error={touched.variable && Boolean(errors.variable)}
        />
      )}
    />
    <br />
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      multiline
      rows={5}
      name="message"
      type="text"
      value={values.message}
      onChange={handleChange}
      onBlur={handleBlur}
      helperText={touched.message ? errors.message : ""}
      error={touched.message && Boolean(errors.message)}
      fullWidth
    />
  </CardContent>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you as asking for or what the issue is? What does "I want that variables will be deleted as a whole and not editable" mean? Sounds like you want to populate a textfield with a value and make it not editable. Is this correct?

Comment: @DrewReese. Yes, that value that is appended to `message TextField` that has `{ }` in the `message TextField` would not be editable. The reason for that is because the backend reads that dynamic { } when I pass it.

Comment: Sorry, `{}` is common JSX syntax for any prop value, are you specifically referring to `value={values.message}` you want to be "locked" and uneditable?

Comment: @DrewReese. I mean the `Autocomplete` has ones with the `{any fields}`. When I select on it. It appends its  `{any fields}` to the `message TextField`. That `{any fields}` coming from `Autocomplete` should not be editable in the `message TextField`. `{any fields}` means either `{name}`, `{address}`, `{email}`

Comment: Are the "{ xxxx }" text snippets always appended to the end? Can/should the user be able to add more than one? It sounds like you want to be able to "insert" any number of these snippets into the text and allow only the text around them to be editable. Is this correct? Once they are added, they cannot be removed?

Comment: @Drew Reese. No. the `{ xxxx }` can be put anywhere. Yes, they can be added more than one. Yes, the user can still type on the `message TextField`. `{xxxx}` can be removed as  a whole  because that `{ xxxx}` are read by backend, thats why they cant be edited or remove some part of `{xxxx}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235645/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-gray-singh).

Comment: @DrewReese. Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I think what you're asking is how to embed material ui `chip` inside `TextField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to allow specific tokens appended to the end of the text that if ever they are edited that they are completely removed. I have found a way to do this with a couple regular expressions and string replace.

There are two basic cases to cover:

- Case 1: A closed token, i.e. `{.....}`.
- Case 2: An Open token, i.e. `aA....}`, `{....zZ`.

Code:

```
// token values
const variables = ["name", "address", "email"];

// closed tokens
const closedRegex = /\s{[^\s]*}/g;

// Checks if closed token has valid values
const closedReplacer = (match) =>
  new RegExp(`{(${variables.join("|")})}`).test(match) ? match : "";

// open tokens
const openRegex = /{[^}\s]*(?:\s|$)|(?:^|\s)[^{\s]*}/g;
```

From the `Formik` function, create a custom change handler so you can intercept the input's `onChange` event object.

```
<Formik
  ...
>
  {({
    ...
    handleChange,
    ...
  }) => {
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replaceAll(openRegex, "");
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replaceAll(
        closedRegex,
        closedReplacer
      );

      handleChange(e);
    };
```

Since the `variables` array values had the brackets stripped out for regex use, add them back in for the `AutoComplete` options.

```
<Autocomplete
  ...
  options={variables.map((el) => `{${el}}`)}
  ...
/>
```

Attach the custom `changeHandler` function to the `TextField`.

```
<TextField
  ...
  onChange={changeHandler}
  ...
/>
```

[image: Edit Formik, Material UI and Yup (forked)]

Comment: Hello Drew. Could you clear out the errors in console? Thank you.

Comment: @GraySingh Can you clarify what errors you are seeing in the console?